# Can't resolve 'fs' in angular

Tags: json2html

Getting error "Can't resolve 'fs'"  in angular

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-json2html/node.json2html.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Projects\bvd-ui-app\node_modules\node-json2html'

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-json2html/node.json2html.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\bvd-ui-app\node_modules\node-json2html'

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-json2html/node.json2html.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in 'C:\Projects\bvd-ui-app\node_modules\node-json2html'

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of Node and Angular you're using.